# Rancher 2.0 Cannot Pull Image

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, rancher

I'm currently on Rancher 2.0. I'm going through the Quick Start Guide on their site: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/quick-start-guide/#provision-a-linux-host

I'm getting stuck deploying a workload. When I try to deploy workload with nginx as per instruction, it always shows as unavailable. Looking at the logs, I see this standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"

I've tried to pull from a private registry too but it still doesn't work even with the private registry added

How do I go about diagnosing and fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All you need to do is edit /etc/sysconfig/docker and remove --selinux-enabled from the OPTIONS variable.